# How can I target the parent of a class with CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

i.e.: I'd like to target the `<div>` elements of class a1, but not a2, a3. Same for the next one a2, but not a1, a3.

I am trying to build a filtering tool. But the tricky part is that I cannot use classes on the `<div>` elements because other people with no HTML background need to edit them on a CMS platform and I can't add classes to such `<div>` elements.

```
<div>
 <h1>Name</h1>
 <ul>
   <li class="a1">Test</li>
   <li class="a2">Test</li>
   <li class="a3">Test</li>
 </ul>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div>
 <h1>Name</h1>
 <ul>
   <li class="a1">Test</li>
   <li class="a2">Test</li>
   <li class="a3">Test</li>
 </ul>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div>
 <h1>Name</h1>
 <ul>
   <li class="a1">Test</li>
   <li class="a2">Test</li>
   <li class="a3">Test</li>
 </ul>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div>
 <h1>Name</h1>
 <ul>
   <li class="a1">Test</li>
   <li class="a2">Test</li>
   <li class="a3">Test</li>
 </ul>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for letting me pick your brain

Comment: You can select the li in javascript with the class and then select the closest div

Answer (score 0):

There is a pseudo-class selector you could use [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), however, no browser has implemented it yet. Actually it is not intended at all to be used in stylesheets, thus your only option would be either way the JavaScript.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('li.a1')].map(x => x.closest('div').classList.add('X'))
```

```css
.X {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <h1>Name</h1>
 <ul>
   <li class="a1">Test</li>
   <li class="a2">Test</li>
   <li class="a3">Test</li>
 </ul>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div>
 <h1>Name</h1>
 <ul>
   <li class="a1">Test</li>
   <li class="a2">Test</li>
   <li class="a3">Test</li>
 </ul>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div>
 <h1>Name</h1>
 <ul>
   <li class="a1">Test</li>
   <li class="a2">Test</li>
   <li class="a3">Test</li>
 </ul>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div>
 <h1>Name</h1>
 <ul>
   <li class="a1">Test</li>
   <li class="a2">Test</li>
   <li class="a3">Test</li>
 </ul>
 <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you would be better served finding out the class/id of the elements that will be surrounding the div (If it is through a CMS there will be something and it likely be unique from anything you are using)  and then using selectors get the children. Targeting a parent element is not really how selectors are designed to work.